# How to convert the dummy variable columns in to several columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I know how to unstack rows into columns, but how to deal with the following `dataframe`?

| date | dummy | avg | lable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-19 | 1 | 20 | l1 |
| 1-19 | 0 | 40 | l1 |
| 1-27 | 1 | 100 | l2 |
| 1-27 | 0 | 140 | l2 |

Expected `dataframe`:

| date | avg_t | avg_c | lable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-19 | 20 | 40 | l1 |
| 1-27 | 100 | 140 | l2 |

The `avg` is 20 when `dummy` equals 1 and it is renamed to `avg_t` as a column. Similar to the column `avg_c`.

I tried:

```
df.groupby(['dummy','avg']).size().unstack
```

But, It does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and then use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = (df.assign(new = df['dummy'].map({0:'c', 1:'t'}))
        .pivot(['date','lable'], 'new', 'avg')
        .add_prefix('avg_')
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

print (df)
   date lable  avg_c  avg_t
0  1-19    l1     40     20
1  1-27    l2    140    100
```

Comment: Can I do it use df[['avg_t']] = df[df['dummy'] == 1]['avg'] ?

Comment: @KT.Thompson - No, need pivoting like answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `pivot_wider` from `janitor`:.

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_wider(index = ['date', 'lable'], names_from = 'dummy')

Out[19]: 
   date lable  avg_0  avg_1
0  1-19    l1     40     20
1  1-27    l2    140    100
```

if you want the `t` and `c`:

```
(df.assign(dummy = df['dummy'].map({0:'c', 1:'t'})).
    pivot_wider(index = ['date', 'lable'], names_from = 'dummy'))

Out[20]: 
   date lable  avg_c  avg_t
0  1-19    l1     40     20
1  1-27    l2    140    100
```

Comment: A very simple way to go. Thanks!